# How can I use drag and drop and multer only for text files and store them in a sqlite db

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am making a web application using node js and I need to upload different text files via multer that works with my input button in HTML. What I have is a drag and drop field that can also be clicked and gives you the option to choose your files. Under the Html is the server code I use multer and SQLite DB. Right now this is not working, how can I connect my HTML with the server or should I do this in my front end js. The final result I am looking to get is to upload the text files in a folder and get their id's stored in my SQLite db file.
This is my HTML and server code

```
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="/public/stylesheets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="drop-zone">
    <form action="/files" method="post"
          enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
    <span class="drop-zone__prompt">Drop file here or click to upload</span>
    <input type="file" name="myFile" class="drop-zone__input">

</div>
<div class = "submit-button">

<input  name="files" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div> 

const db_name = path.join(__dirname, "db", "Database.db");
const db = new sqlite3.Database(db_name, err => {
    if (err) {return console.error(err.message);}
    console.log("Successful connection to the database 'fileData.db'");
});

--------------------------------------------------------------------
const fileStorageEngine = multer.diskStorage({
     destination: (req,file , cb) =>{
         cb(null,db);
     },
    filename: (req,file,cb)=>{
         cb(null, file.orignalname);
    },
});
const upload = multer({storage:fileStorageEngine});

application.post('/files',upload.array("files",4),(req , res)=>{
    console.log(req.files);
    res.send("Files successfully uploaded")
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Please give name "files" to the file input type and try.

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't work. Postman does but nothing else seems to...

Comment: accessing file from server part application.post('/files',upload.array("files",4),(req , res)
in the client 
<input type="file" name="myFile" class="drop-zone__input"> should be replaced by 
 <input type="file" name="files" class="drop-zone__input">  . This is the issue I wanted to point out.